# Python lowest price in dictionary

Tags: python

This is a follow up question. I know how to remove minimum in a list with `remove(min())` but not dictionary. I'm trying to remove the lowest price in the dictionarys in Python.

```
shops['foodmart'] = [12.33,5.55,1.22]
shops['gas_station'] = [0.89,45.22]
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the list has the same lowest price twice, e.g. `[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0]`?  Should both 1s be removed or only one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically, for the example given :

```
shops['foodmart'].remove(min(shops["foodmart"]))
```

More generally, for the whole dictionary :

```
for shop in shops :
    shops[shop].remove(min(shops[shop]))
```

The logic is the same as removing values from a list which you mention you know. `shops[shop]` is in itself a list as well in your case. So what you do on lists, is applicable here as well.

A faster and cleaner method as suggested by Lattyware would be :

```
for prices in shops.values():
    prices.remove(min(prices))
```

Comment: Note that this is a bit weird, as you loop over the keys, but you want the values. `for prices in shops.values():`, ``prices.remove(min(prices))`` would be shorter, clearer and faster.

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, you are absolutely correct. Thanks. I hadnt mentioned it because it was already there in another answer by that time.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> shops={}
>>> shops['foodmart'] = [12.33,5.55,1.22]
>>> shops['gas_station'] = [0.89,45.22]
>>> shops
{'foodmart': [12.33, 5.55, 1.22], 'gas_station': [0.89, 45.22]}

>>> for x in shops:             #iterate over key
    shops[x].remove(min(shops[x])) # min returns the smallest value and 
                                   # that is passed to remove

>>> shops
{'foodmart': [12.33, 5.55], 'gas_station': [45.22]}
```

or:

```
>>> for values in shops.values():    #iterate over values
...     values.remove(min(values))
...     
>>> shops
{'foodmart': [12.33, 5.55], 'gas_station': [45.22]}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above solution would work if the minimum price is unique, but in case there are more than one minimum values in the list that you need to remove, you can use the following construct

```
{k : [e for e in v if e != min(v)] for k, v in shops.items()}
```

The particular thing to note here is that, using list.remove would actually remove the first item from the list which matches the needle (aka the minimum value) but to remove all of the mins at one go, you have to reconstruct the list filtering all items which matches the minimum.
Note, this would be slower than using list.remove, but at the end you have to decide what is your requirement

Unfortunately, though the above construct is terse, yet it ends up calling `min` for each price element for every shop. You may wan't to translate it to a loop construct to reduce the overhead

```
>>> for shop, price in shops.items():
    min_price = min(price)
    while min_price in price:
        shops[shop].remove(min_price)


>>> shops
{'foodmart': [12.33], 'toy_store': [15.32], 'gas_station': [45.22], 'nike': [69.99]}
>>>
```